# Any way I can add "Orange" theme or composed look within onet.xml or feature staple, office 365?

Tags: office-365

I need to provision themes for a newly created web, either by object model JSOM or by modifying onet.xml for the web template, this has to work on office 365.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.ThmxTheme' does not contain a
>   definition for 'GetManagedThemes'

Please answer, only if you can tell me how to make it work.

Do-not say that it's not possible to do so, as I know that already know that straight away its not possible by searching for hours and hours. Thank You.

I am looking for a hack or work around.

**I want orange.**

[image]

Comment: If you do find a "hack" you'll have effectively broken the concept of Code Access Security which was a core component of the .NET Framework. This is the reason it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe GetManagedThemes method should also be removed from the problem definition? Provisioning themes includes the Get operation, but getting themes is mostly related to getting .thmx files from the themes gallery.

Comment: Why don't you use Composed Looks? They're easier to manage, easier to build and are better supported.

Comment: Hi @JamesLove , any tutorial plzz, all i want is the "orange" theme or composed look from the out of box settings in site, to be applied to my new subweb created

Comment: @CustomizedName you should also put this in feedback for o365 community so that they will consider making that method available in next version.

Comment: Btw, that screenshot above of "Change the Look" isn't from the Thmx engine, those are Composed Looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a .spcolor file with the palette you want, and upload that into the Theme Gallery (access this via Site Settings, or use a module to upload it if you're in a feature - either way reember to put it into the 15 folder) you can apply a color palette file to a site by calling Web.ApplyTheme:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.applytheme(v=office.15).aspx

You don't need to set a font or a background image, just pass string.Empty to these.

This page describes the SharePoint Color Palette Tool to help you create your spcolor file:

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-sharepoint2013-theme-using-color-palette-tool

Comment: string.empty doesn't work, had to send "null"

Comment: i upvoted you but it's office 365. cannot touch 15 folder

Comment: even though your answer isn't complete, but it helped me putting me in the right direction, i used web.applytheme at end as it's available in jcsom

Comment: There's a 15 folder in the theme gallery, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test the code, but I think you can set the theme by using a feature receiver.

Inside the `FeatureActivated` method put:

```
// Get the SPColor file
var colorPaletteFile = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette015.spcolor";

// Get the SPFont file. 
var fontSchemeFile = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/SharePointPersonality.spfont";


// Now apply your theme to the site.
web.ApplyTheme(colorPaletteFile, fontSchemeFile, "", true);
```

In the code snippet, note that I used `Palette015.spcolor` and `SharePointPersonality.spfont`. These are the files used by the OOTB orange theme.

You can include the feature in the onet.xml file (under WebFeatures) or attach the feature to an existing template with feature stapling.

See [this blog](http://yuriburger.net/2013/03/24/deploying-and-activating-sharepoint-2013-themes-using-visual-studio/) for another example on using web.ApplyTheme

Comment: thanks, but i can't use SPTheme class, it uses Microsoft.SharePoint.Utility namespace which is not available in office 365 client object model

Comment: @CustomizedName Why are you restricted to client object model? With a feature, you can use the server OM

Comment: if it wasn't sandbox, we can simply use ThmxTheme class !! so yes on office 365 only client object model

Comment: @CustomizedName I think you are mistaking client object model and sandbox, which are two totally different things!

Comment: @MdMazzotti I believe web.Update() is missing at the end.

Comment: @StupidOne I reported the snippet found on the MSDN. Feel free to edit the answer, as I cannot test the code and can't really tell if it is needed or not.

Comment: @MdMazzotti I understand your effort to help me but , I know they are different, but look,  SPTHEME class is not available in sandbox, neither in client Object MODEL !! , does that makes it clear enough.

Comment: @MdMazzotti I up voted you for telling me which color platte orange is, thanks, i didn't down voted you before, thank you

Comment: @CustomizedName I'm sorry I cannot test the code, the MSDN says "available for office 365", so I thought this could work. Did you try the method web.ApplyTheme ? this should be available in sandbox

Comment: @CustomizedName I edited my answer with the ApplyTheme method (as also suggested by James Love)

Comment: @CustomizedName thanks but don't worry. I'm glad you found a working solution in the end. Btw, I was adding the comment where I proposed the webApply method while James was adding his answer. He just came first, so he deserved the bounty, no problem